# How do I convert this function to not use the Promise constructor antipattern

Tags: javascript, promise

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838629/how-can-i-make-a-promise-reject-for-testing) and was told to avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern. I read through the article linked but I am unsure how to not use the anti pattern. This is the function:

```
db.getUserCount = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    db.users.count().then(function (result) {
        resolve (result);
    }, function(e) {
        reject (e);
    });
});
```

I have all my database queries coded like the one above. This is my attempt to not use the anti-pattern but as I don't totally understand it I don't think this way is correct either:

```
db.getUserCount = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        db.users.count().then(function (result) {
            return (result);
        }).then(function(result) {
            resolve(result);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
};
```

As I want to be writing good code, if someone could take a minute to show me an example of using the above function by not using the anti-pattern that would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the `db.users.count()` function is an asynchronous operation, then what you've written is not an anti pattern. The "anti pattern" comes in when the method is synchronous, and a promise is returned for the sake of using the Promise Pattern.

The key here is from a quote from another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it#answer-23803744) linked to in the question you reference:

> ... promises are about making **asynchronous code** retain most of the lost properties of synchronous code such as flat indentation and one exception channel.

(emphasis, mine)

If the code is not asynchronous, then returning a promise is an anti pattern.

As for returning `new Promise(...)` being an anti pattern? If that's the case then returning `new Anything()` is an anti pattern. Using the Promise constructor is fine.

Comment: This is incorrect and misleading. See the other answer for what's the correct way to write the code.

Comment: Also, your emphasis is not what the quote means at all. I know because you're quoting me there. Promises give you chaining for free and you only need to use `new Promise` when _converting_ an API to promises, it's pointless in an already promised API.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I missed the fact that the code in the question already returned a promise, but my statement still stands: "f the code is not asynchronous, then returning a promise is an anti pattern." It just so happens that the code in the question *is* already asynchronous and returning a promise, making the new promise useless.

Comment: Right, so now your statement is correct - but not useful to the OP :P

Answer (score 5):

Since `db.users.count()` seems to return a promise already, you can just do this:

```
db.getUserCount = function () {
    return db.users.count();
});
```

There's not need to wrap it in an additional promise (using `new Promise(...)`).

Comment: Thanks! I was wrapping all my queries in an extra promise and there was no need. That must be the reason I could never reach the reject part in my tests also.